# Full namespacing requires recompilation

Tags: namespaces, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Say I have two files:

```
foo.re
bar.re
```

Say I now have, at the top of `bar.re`

```
open MyProject.Foo;
```

This fails to compile with:

```
This module is not a structure; it has type
  (module MyProject.Foo)
```

If I rerun compilation, everything works fine

If I change that line to just `open Foo;` everything compiles fine.

Why am I observing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

ReasonML treats each file as a module, the practice is to uppercase the file name so

```
Foo.re
Bar.re
```

let's also suppose that we define a function in Foo call bar and another in Bar call foo.

so we would have:

```
/* Inside Foo.re */
let bar = string => {}

/* Inside Bar.re */
let foo = string => {}
```

from with another module, which we have called Main.re, we can reference the above as.

```
let myResult = Foo.bar("happy");
let ourResult = Bar.foo("days);
```

or

```
open Foo, Bar;

let myResult = bar("happy");
let ourResult = foo("days");
```

So when asked for `open MyProject.Foo`, you were asking for the submodule Foo within the module MyProject, which does not exist. Of course, if you created `MyProject.re` and added a module to that file called `Foo`, then your `open MyProject.Foo` would work fine.

Further references:

The underlying [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html) which the reasonML modules are based on.
The [Basic modules](http://reasonmlhub.com/exploring-reasonml/ch_basic-modules.html) section from Axel Rauschmayer book on ReasonML